# append tinestamp to the filename using groovy

Tags: groovy, timestamp, soapui

I have n number of test cases in SoapUI. I am creating a report which contains test results of all the test cases. Suppose I have 3 test cases. I have used groovy script for all the upcoming statements. I have an input file through which I'm reading properties to my soapUI test cases. I'm creating the report by copying the input excel sheet and creating one more sheet and write the results of 1st test case.

Now the created output excel sheet will be copied and one more sheet is created and now results of 2nd test case are written in this. Like this it happens for all the test cases.I want my output file name to be appended by the current timestamp.For this I have used the below groovy code. And this groovy code is added in the last test case.

So in future if I add more number of test cases then I need to move the groovy code (append time stamp) to last test case. In order to avoid adding script manually to the last test case I want to add a code which makes sure that all the test cases are being executed and then timestamp is appended to the file name. Is it possible to achieve this?

[image: Attached the screenshot of output excel file pattern]

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils
def count=0, i=1, j=1
def inputFileName, outputFileName
def outputFile = new File(testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("outputFileName"))
today = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSS Z")
def fileWithoutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("outputFileName"))
outputFile.renameTo(new File(fileWithoutExt + "_" + today + ".xls"))][1]
```

Comment: create a separate test case that just writes the file and keep it last...

Comment: Anyhow doing that also is a manual task right!!

Comment: Why do you want to create a new file and then rename it?  Would it not be better to create the file with the intended name?

Comment: Because I'm reusing the file in consequent test cases. If I create initially with the timestamp, I cannot write a generic code

Comment: Are you saying that the next test run uses the same file name to write test result and data is overridden. So you want to backup the previous test result file?